# JPA @Version behavior when data is changed from unmanaged connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Enabling `@Version` on table `Customer` when running the tests below

```java
@Test
public void actionsTest1 () throws InterruptedException {
    CustomerState t = customerStateRepository.findById(1L).get();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    t.setInvoiceNumber("1");
    customerStateRepository.save(t);
}
```

While `actionsTest1` is sleeping, I run `actionsTest2` which updates the invoice number to 2.

```java
@Test
public void actionsTest2 () throws InterruptedException {
    CustomerState t = customerStateRepository.findById(1L).get();
    t.setInvoiceNumber("2");
    customerStateRepository.save(t);
}
```

When actionsTest1 returns from sleeping it tries to update too, and gets a  `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`

Works as expected.

But if I run `actionsTest1`  and while it is sleeping I open a SQL terminal and do a raw update of

```sql
update customer 
set invoice_number='3' where id=1
```

When `actionsTest1` returns from sleeping, its versioning mechanism doesn't catch the case and updates the value back to 1.

Is that expected behavior?  Does versioning work only with connections managed by JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. If you do a update manually, you have to update your version as well.

If you using JPA with @Version, JPA is incrementing the version column.

To get your expected result you have to write the statement like this

```
update customer set invoice_number='3', version=XYZ (mabye version+1) where id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is that expected behavior?

Yes.

> Does versioning work only with connections managed by JPA?

No, it also works when using any other way of updating your data. But everything updating the data has to adhere to the rules of optimistic locking:

1. increment the version column whenever performing any update
2. (only required when the other process also want to detect concurrent updates): on every update check that the version number hasn't changes since the data on which the update is based was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate automatically increases/changes the value in `@Version` mapped column in your database.

When you fetch an entity  record, hibernate keeps a copy of the  record of the data along with the value of `@Version`. While performing a `merge` or `update` operation, hibernate checks if the current value in of Version is still the same and matches the copy of entity fetched earlier.
If the value matches, it means that the entity is not dirty(not updated by any other transaction) else an exception is thrown.